# Ouput to text file Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

For an assignment I'm doing, I need to crack a locked PDF File. I'm trying to create a password list in order to do so, but cannot work out how to output the results this code produces into a text file.

```
from random import shuffle
with open('randomwords.txt', 'r') as data:
    data = data.read().split()
    while(True):
        shuffle(data)
        password = ''
        for x in data[:3]:
            password += x
        print password.replace('o','0')
```

Everything I've tried so far hasn't worked, would be appreciated if someone could show me how to output the results this code produces into an external text file.

Transform fucntion:

```
def transform(word):
    from random import shuffle
    with open('randomwords.txt', 'r') as data:
            data = data.read().split()
        while(True):
                shuffle(data)
                password = ''
                for x in data[:3]:
                        password += x
                print password.replace('o','0')
    return word
```

Comment: Well it seems like you know how to open a file, so open a file in write mode and instead of printing, write to that file. Also you have an infinite loop, which would be bad if you are writing to a file...

Comment: http://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/reading_writing_methods.html

Comment: What results need writing to an external file? You don't have any results

Answer (score 0):

You might need to open another file to write your output.

```
from random import shuffle


def transform(word):
    l = list(word)
    shuffle(l)
    new_word = ''.join(l)
    return new_word[:3].replace('o', '0')


input_file = 'randomwords.txt'
output_file = 'passwords.txt'
with open(input_file, 'r') as word_file:
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as pwd_file:
        for r in word_file:
            word = r.strip()
            password = transform(word)
            pwd_file.write(password + '\n')
```

Reference: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: This kind of works, however the output file is empty when I view it.

Comment: @Quarismo Interesting. Could you share your transform function? I put orange\ncolor\n in randomwords.txt for testing and it works.

Comment: Sure, I've added it into the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by orange\ncolor\n?

Comment: @Quarismo It means

orange
color

\n is new line char

Comment: Just think like this. Read one line from text file and write the line into another text file.